# Issue getting Ubuntu 23.04 to start from Live USB

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

On a new build running:

- AMD 7900X
- ROG B650E-F
- Nvidia 4090

When booting from the USB I get:

`config failed, hub 7.01 not recognized`

`nouveau not found`

If I plug my DP into the AMD iGPU, sometimes it might boot into. Login screen is fine but past it, the screen is full white with only cursor visible.

I tested on PopOS Nvidia version and it all works fine.

Comment: I think the problem is that your live Ubuntu version cannot manage the nvidia chip/card. Try with the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset`. If that works, you can install Ubuntu and after installation (and booting with nomodeset) it should be possible to install a proprietary nvidia driver and take full advantage of the graphics hardware.

Comment: @sudodus thanks, I will try that approach.

Comment: You can check which version of the nvidia driver, that is used by PopOS, and try with that version (after you have installed Ubuntu).

Comment: That worked. But I still see config failed. Hub 7.01 not found. @sudodus

Comment: I don't know what is meant by 'Hub 7.01'. Can you guess what it is? Does anybody else know what it is? Is some internal or external device connected, that is seen as a hub?

Comment: Seems to be gone now. By best guess was the new amd 7900x needs some newer packages.